# Gitlab CI Lint Api

Tags: bash, gitlab-ci, jq, gitlab-api

Lately, I have been trying to access the Gitlab CI Lint Api via bash using curl.
for that I have been trying to strictly follow the documentation on [Gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/lint.html).
According to the Gitlab documentation this fragment should return the formatted yml:

```
jq --null-input --arg yaml "$(<example-gitlab-ci.yml)" '.content=$yaml' \
| curl "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/ci/lint?include_merged_yaml=true" \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data @- \
| jq --raw-output '.merged_yaml | fromjson'
```

I hove modified the Request with my credentials and I get a valid response, when I shorten the jq query to

`jq --raw-output '.merged_yaml'`

and I recieve

```
"---
\".api_test\":
  rules:
  - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE==\"merge_request_event\"
    changes:
    - src/api/*
deploy:
  rules:
  - when: manual
    allow_failure: true
  extends:
  - \".api_test\"
  script:
  - echo \"hello world\"
","includes":[],"jobs":[{"name":"deploy","stage":"test","before_script":[],"script":["echo \"hello world\""],"after_script":[],"tag_list":[],"only":null,"except":null,"environment":null,"when":"on_success","allow_failure":false,"needs":null}],"status":"valid"}
```

When i let this code run with the `fromjson` option I get an error:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0 (while parsing '---
".api_test":
  rules:
[...]
```

I am at the End of my wits, pls help me!

Comment: Did you ment to use [tag:yq] ?

Comment: `jq` is a JSON tool, not a YAML tool. Every JSON document is a valid YAML document, but not the other way round. jq cannot parse YAML documents.

Comment: gojq is an implementation of jq that can both handle YAML input and provide YAML output.

Answer (score 1):

[jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is a *JSON* processor. A YAML document is not JSON (but a JSON document is a YAML document). YAML is a superset of JSON.

There are other tools to process YAML, such as [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), which uses the familiar syntax from jq, but doesn't support every feature of jq.

So you will probably need run something similar to the following:

```
curl … | yq '.merged_yaml' | yq '…'
```

or perhaps (but that shouldn't be required, since `yq` can handle JSON files just fine):

```
curl … | jq '.merged_yaml' | yq '…'
```

---

EDIT:

I think you found a bug in GitLab's documentation.

```
jq --null-input --arg yaml "$(<example-gitlab-ci.yml)" '.content=$yaml' \
| curl "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/ci/lint?include_merged_yaml=true" \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data @- \
| jq --raw-output '.merged_yaml | fromjson'
```

Should actually not use the `fromjson` filter:

```
jq --null-input --arg yaml "$(<example-gitlab-ci.yml)" '.content=$yaml' \
| curl "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/ci/lint?include_merged_yaml=true" \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data @- \
| jq --raw-output '.merged_yaml'
```

Everything in the first part of this answer still holds: jq cannot process YAML, you need yq for that. (But the GitLab docs never process the YAML document, they only print it)

Comment: I very much appreciat the answer, though I get a parsing error here aswell
`parse error: Invalid string: control characters from U+0000 through U+001F must be escaped at line 621, column 1
`

Comment: also they use jq in the docs, so I have to image that it should work with that aswell...

Comment: @EdgyCoder Can you link the docs you are referencing? And what is line 621 of the YAML? Looks like it contains non-printable control characters

Comment: @EdgyCoder if you are talking about <https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/04/21/devops-workflows-json-format-jq-ci-cd-lint/>, they never use `jq` to parse the YAML document, they only print it

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/lint.html

Comment: I also referenced this in my post

Comment: @EdgyCoder Ah, I missed the link in the original post. Thanks for linking again. I think you found a bug in the documentation. I tried the examples from the docs and I get an error from `jq` too. But the YAML is already stored as a string, so you should be able to simple run `jq -r '.merged_yaml'` – the yaml is never processed further, only pretty-printed